# SonarQube Treemap code coverage threshold

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, treemap

We are running SonarQube 5.1.2 and have Treemap dashboard with rectangles that display color from red to green based on the code coverage. Do you know how can I set what's the code coverage threshold for the red/green color?
I thought it was in quality gates but it does not seem to be so. I also don't see what the default value used by Sonar is.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as far as I know currently there is no such configuration option.

It's funny that I wrote a feedback message and new feature request on this topic a few minutes ago on SQ's mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/Z4GK3gNJ3YU

It would be great if you could post a message there to show that it's a feature I'm not the only one to request ;-)

Cheers,